# Webpack config file for large non-SPA site, with src modules outside of Webpack root, and outputting modules in their own split chunks?

Tags: webpack

I'm posting this webpack.config so that it might help others down their Webpack learning path, this config is working for me. I do front-end for a very large, non-SPA website. My goals were to: 1) have 1 Webpack root for entire site and be able to specify what entry point to build based upon CLI arguments, 2) output common/shared code and entry-specific code in their own folders and bundles, and 3) ensure that common/shared code isn't duplicated in various bundles. Suggestions for improvements gratefully accepted, or if you have questions about aspects of this config let me know in the comments.

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = env => {
  // entry point and output locations are configured via cli args
  const environment = env.environment ? env.environment : "";
  const site = env.site ? env.site : "";
  const pagetemplate = env.pagetemplate ? env.pagetemplate : "";
  const page = env.page ? env.page : "";

  if (environment && site && pagetemplate && page) {
    const entryobject = (page => {
      switch (page) {
        case "layouttype1":
          return {
            page: "./src/mywebsite/pages/layouttype1entrymodule/index.js"
          };
        case "testpage1":
          return { testpage1: "./src/mywebsite/pages/testpage1/index.js" };
        case "testpage2":
          return { testpage1: "./src/mywebsite/pages/testpage2/index.js" };
        default:
          return { page: "./src/modules/page/index.js" };
      }
    })(page);

    return {
      entry: entryobject, // entry
      output: {
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        path: path.join(__dirname, `dist/${environment}/${site}/${page}`),
        publicPath: "/folder/folder/folder/"
      }, // output
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: "babel-loader", // transpile es6 to es5
                options: {
                  presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
                }
              }
            ] // use
          },
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
              { loader: "style-loader" },
              {
                loader: "css-loader"
              }
            ] // use
          },
          {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: "style-loader"
              },
              {
                loader: "css-loader"
              },
              {
                loader: "sass-loader"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff)$/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: "file-loader",
                options: {
                  name: "[path][name].[ext]"
                } // options
              } // loader
            ] // use
          },
          {
            test: /\.(gif|jpg|png)$/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: "url-loader"
              } // loader
            ] // use
          },
          {
            test: /\.(svg)$/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: "svg-url-loader"
              } // loader
            ] // use
          }
        ] // rules
      }, // module
      plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: "./src/index.html" }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          "process.env.environment": JSON.stringify(environment),
          "process.env.site": JSON.stringify(site),
          "process.env.pagetemplate": JSON.stringify(pagetemplate),
          "process.env.page": JSON.stringify(page)
        })
      ], // plugins
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          maintemplate: path.resolve(
            __dirname,
            "src/maintemplate/maintemplate.js"
          ),
          sitewide: path.resolve(
            __dirname,
            "src/mywebsite/modules/sitewide/sitewide.js"
          ),
          layouttype1: path.resolve(
            __dirname,
            "src/mywebsite/modules/layouts/layouttype1/layouttype1.js"
          )
        },
        modules: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, "src/maintemplate/node_modules"),
          path.resolve(
            __dirname,
            "src/mywebsite/modules/sitewide/node_modules"
          ),
          path.resolve(
            __dirname,
            "src/mywebsite/modules/layouts/layouttype1/node_modules"
          ),
          "node_modules"
        ]
      }, // resolve
      optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        splitChunks: {
          chunks: "all",
          minSize: 0,
          maxSize: 0,
          minChunks: 1,
          maxAsyncRequests: 5,
          maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
          automaticNameDelimiter: "~",
          automaticNameMaxLength: 30,
          name: true,
          cacheGroups: {
            vendors: false,
            default: false,
            layouttype1: {
              chunks: "all",
              test: /[\\/]layouttype1[\\/]/,
              name: "layouttype1",
              filename: `../[name]/[name].bundle.js`
            },
            maintemplate: {
              chunks: "all",
              test: /[\\/]maintemplate[\\/]/,
              name: "maintemplate",
              filename: `../[name]/[name].bundle.js`
            },
            gsap2: {
              chunks: "all",
              test: /[\\/]gsap2[\\/]/,
              name: "gsap2",
              filename: `../shared/[name].bundle.js`,
              priority: 100
            },
            jquery3: {
              chunks: "all",
              test: /[\\/]jquery3[\\/]/,
              name: "jquery3",
              filename: `../shared/[name].bundle.js`,
              priority: 100
            },
            sitewide: {
              chunks: "all",
              test: /[\\/]sitewide[\\/]/,
              name: "sitewide",
              filename: `../[name]/[name].bundle.js`
            }
          }
        }
      }
    };
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this as a resource for others using Webpack, in case some of it's helpful.

Comment: OK somewhat embarrassingly I have to admit that since I posted this I've learned about Webpack's dynamic imports feature, which combined with its magic comments makes the SplitChunks cacheGroups irrelevant for my purposes. The dynamic import syntax can auto-bundle modules in their own files with custom names set via magic comment /* webpackChunkName: "custombundkenamehere" */